# How can I read two JSON files with different data at the same time?

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson

**My *part* of the task is:**

---

I need to collect `productId`-s into list from two `JSON` files with different data and pass it into the *custom method* with `directory` of `JSON` files.

I have *two* `JSON` files with *different data* as the following:

1. [JSON №1](https://gist.github.com/invzbl3/29a298bc757dfaa4717901eaa3bc9a55)
2. [JSON №2](https://gist.github.com/invzbl3/98b6d8c8589f795ea6feafcea0fe9d04)

And my `code` is in the next format:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        InputStream isOne = JSONParser.class.getResourceAsStream("/test/java/resources/json/file/product_0001690510.json");
        InputStream isTwo = JSONParser.class.getResourceAsStream("/test/java/resources/json/file/product_0001694109.json");

        // ... need to use somehow InpuStream for reading two JSON files with different structure inside

        JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("products"); // notice that `"products": [...]` 
        String productId = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
            productId = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("productID");
        }

        List<String> productIds = new ArrayList<>(Collections.singleton(productId));

        for (var file : obj.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(getAllExportsWithProductIds(file, productIds));
        }
    }

    public static List<String> getAllExportsWithProductIds(String directory, List<String> productIds) throws IOException {
        var matchingObjects = new ArrayList<String>();
        try (var fileStream = Files.walk(Path.of(directory))) {
            for (var file : fileStream.toList()) {
                var json = Json.readString(Files.readString(file));
                var objects = JsonDecoder.array(json);

                for (var object : objects) {
                    var objectProductIDs = JsonDecoder.field(
                            object, "products",
                            JsonDecoder.array(JsonDecoder.field("productID", JsonDecoder::string))
                    );
                    for (var productId : objectProductIDs) {
                        if (productIds.contains(productId)) {
                            matchingObjects.add(Json.writeString(object));
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return matchingObjects;
    }
}
```

[Full code](https://gist.github.com/invzbl3/ff22dc4711578a06d83d0cde4e843d21)

Based on it *my question* is:

Can I read all provided `JSON` files at the same time to collect `productId`-s into list? If yes, how can I do that if I have the different data of two `JSON` files.

To *clarify* a bit:

> "*By different data*, I mean, in general, the `number` of these fields
> (*for example*, `productId` fields in both of `JSON`-s: [№1](https://gist.github.com/invzbl3/29a298bc757dfaa4717901eaa3bc9a55#file-json-1-L12) and [№2](https://gist.github.com/invzbl3/98b6d8c8589f795ea6feafcea0fe9d04#file-json-2-L10)
> accordingly), their order. That is, how an [array object](https://gist.github.com/invzbl3/29a298bc757dfaa4717901eaa3bc9a55#file-json-1-L2) differs from
> [another](https://gist.github.com/invzbl3/98b6d8c8589f795ea6feafcea0fe9d04#file-json-2-L2).
>
> If these `JSON`-s have the same data, it'd be easier to parse, but
> in this specific usecase I need to find the way how to handle both of
> them in different way as their data is not in the same format of representation."

My *detailed* explanation how I see it in abstract way:

[How I see it abstractly in the lifecycle of developing.](https://gist.github.com/invzbl3/bdc0c3e743002fd332fb6b07eb4b8a8d)

I've already read different articles and checked libraries as:

1. [java-jq](https://github.com/arakelian/java-jq)
2. [Jackson object mapper tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial)

and so on,

but I'm still struggling with understanding how to apply it correctly, for this reason, I'm looking for a concrete solution.

Thank you in advance for any smart and helpful ideas. If you need some additional details, I'm ready to provide without any problem.

---

**UPD:**

There's I have another version of code, which is collecting `productID`-s, I need just to find the way how to combine with the first version of code and that's it:

```
public class ProductIdImporter {
    public ProductIdImporter() {
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void importJson() {
        List<Path> paths = Arrays.asList(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\pc\\IdeaProjects\\jsonapi\\src\\test\\java\\resources\\json\\product_0001690510.json"),
                                         Paths.get("C:\\Users\\pc\\IdeaProjects\\jsonapi\\src\\test\\java\\resources\\json\\product_0001694109.json"));
        ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        Set<String> productIds = paths.stream().map(path -> {
                    try {
                        return jsonMapper.readValue(Files.newInputStream(path), ExportList[].class);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }).map(Arrays::asList)
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .map(ExportList::productList)
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .map(Product::getId)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        productIds.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProductIdImporter importer = new ProductIdImporter();
        importer.importJson();
    }

    static class ExportList {
        public List<Product> products;

        public ExportList() {
        }

        public List<Product> productList() {
            return products;
        }
    }

    static class Product {
        public String productID;

        public Product() {
        }

        public String getId() {
            return productID;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I have understood well you want to extract the `String` list of `ProductID` from the files with different format, if you think it's helpful as an example I can extract the list from the first file with `jackson`.

Comment: @dariosicily, 
Yes, exactly, you're right. I'd really appreciate your help. I need to extract `ProductId` and then pass it to the custom method with directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the [JSON №1](https://gist.github.com/invzbl3/29a298bc757dfaa4717901eaa3bc9a55) you have included in your post basically it is an array of json objects with the same format like below (I have included just the first one element and deleted all the properties you are not interested to parse):

```
[{
    "products": [
      {
        "colorWayID": "IMP5002620012114",
        "productID": "0001755256"
      },
      {
        "colorWayID": "IMP8473190012114",
        "productID": "0001690510"
      },
      {
        "colorWayID": "IMP9100570012114",
        "productID": "0001700877"
      }
    ],
    ...other properties excluded from parsing
}]
```

To iterate over this array you can read your json file into a `ArrayNode` and iterate over every element:

```
ArrayNode arrayNode = (ArrayNode) mapper.readTree(json);
for (int i = 0; i < arrayNode.size(); ++i) {/*inspecting products property*/}
```

The *products* property is an array of `JsonNode` containing the *productID* property you want to extract, you can use the [`JsonNode#get`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.14/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#get-java.lang.String-) method to extract both the *products* and *productID* properties:

```
List<String> productIds = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayNode arrayNode = (ArrayNode) mapper.readTree(json);
for (int i = 0; i < arrayNode.size(); ++i) {
    //products property is also an array
    ArrayNode products =(ArrayNode) arrayNode.get(i).get("products");
    for (int j = 0; j < products.size(); ++j) {
        //adding productId to your list
        productIds.add(products.get(j).get("productID").asText());
    }  
}
```

This process can be repeated for other json files with variations depending from the json structure contained in them, but substantially it remains the same.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your effort to help me. I'll play now with your code and mark your answer as a correct one after testing and applying it in one of my version of code.